# Usar ou não variáveis para definir um objeto?

Tags: php, classes, variáveis, objetos

Recentemente assistindo alguns tutoriais, vejo programadores omitindo as variáveis em bloco de código. Não sei como se chama essa prática, mas gostaria de saber se é recomendada, quais as vantagens e desvantagens em seu uso, e se a forma como coloquei está correta. A questão é que está funcionando...

Exemplo:

```
$head = new MakeHead("Title");
    $head->_addmenu("180","./insert");
    $head->_addtoggle('190', 'toggle', 'bar');
$head->_printhead();
```

Para:

```
(new MakeHead("Title"))
    ->_addmenu("180","./insert")
    ->_addtoggle('190', 'togglesearch', 'searchbar')
->_printhead();
```

Comment: Não vejo vantagens, apenas as desvantagens em que você perde completamente o seu objeto, o que pode dificultar a manutenção do código e operações de depuração, sem contar que, ao meu ver, prejudica a legibilidade do código.

Comment: eu concordo com @Woss, talvez faça sentido usar numa instância que só vai fazer uma operação talvez, mas nesse exemplo faz 3, faria mais sentido ter a variável e ajuda no debug tbm

Comment: Se não está usando variável é quase certo que também não precisava de uma classe.

Comment: Entendi. Apesar de funcionar, o PHPStorm dá um warning dizendo que minha function não é VOID, e mesmo que eu as defina como metodo():void, o PHPStorm remove o warning mas deixa de fornecer os HINTS da classe e dos métodos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta como sempre é Depende.

Antes de decidir se você precisa ou não de uma variável você tem que entender para que você quer o objeto. O objetivo de uma variável é armazenar uma referência a um objeto ou valor para que você possa usar posteriormente, neste sentido se não houver necessidade de usar posteriormente você não precisa armazenar ela em uma variável (ou constante).

Nesse exemplo que você deu nós vemos uma interface fluida, damos este nome a classes cujos métodos retornam uma referência dela mesma ou uma nova instância dela, permitindo invocar um método em cima do retorno do método.

Um exemplo disso pode ser encontrado nas especificações da PSR-7, no qual conforme você invoca os métodos para construir uma mensagem http (ex. Request) você recebe uma nova instância daquela classe podendo encadear chamadas.

Esse tipo de comportamento também é comum no padrão de projeto builder, onde um builder retorna a si mesmo até que um método de construção (ex. make, build ou create) seja chamado retornando o que o builder constrói.

Os principais pontos onde você não precisa ter uma referência em uma variável são:

- Você irá criar o objeto apenas para chamar um método, ex.

```php
(new Logger("Startup"))->log("mensagem");
```

Neste exemplo assumimos que não vamos precisar desta instância de logger após usa-la, se precisássemos poderíamos armazenar a referência dela em uma variável.

- Você irá passar um objeto como parâmetro assim que o criar.

```php
$client->send(new User("João"));
```

Neste exemplo se o objeto é simples e a leitura não fica comprometida você pode instanciar o objeto direto na chamada do método.

> Um ponto importante a lembrar é que você não está programando para o computador entender, você está programando para que humanos (você e quem quer que venha a dar manutenção neste código) entendam o que foi programado, então você deve tentar deixar sempre que possível seu código legível, se isso exigir a criação de variáveis, crie.

> Se você estivesse fazendo código para máquinas apenas você poderia nomear todas as suas variáveis com varNumero, ex. var1, var2, var3, var4, etc, visto que a máquina entenderia, dar nomes que significam algo é algo que fazemos para que nós desenvolvedores consigamos entender o que o programa faz com o mínimo de esforço cognitivo possível.

Comment: Entendi. Então, em outras palavras, no exemplo que postei não seria interessante usar. Basicamente essa rotina cria um cabeçalho na minha página usando um template próprio. Embora não haja nenhum tratamento, apenas execução dos métodos solicitados com as informações passadas

Comment: Olá @EvandroPH, na realidade depende, se for legível para você e o seu time e você não precisar chamar mais esta instância do cabeçalho então você não precisa associar a uma variável. É uma questão de intenção, qual a sua intenção com este objeto, só imprimir o cabeçalho e não fazer mais nada? Neste caso talvez dessa forma funcione melhor. Um conselho que posso dar no entanto é não sacrificar leitura para economizar linhas, o php tem um otimizador que verifica o código antes de executar, então não vai ser declarar uma variável que vai acabar com a performance do seu programa.

Comment: Justamente isso que imaginei. Pesquisei um pouco mais e achei algo sobre o chained methods, que é basicamente isso que mencionei. Na prática não vai mudar muito pra mim não. Na verdade seria apenas por questão de indentação do código mesmo. O PHPStorm indenta corretamente se eu uso o Chained Method, se eu não usar ele remove as indentações.